# Error javascript código

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo resolver este error?

```js
module.exports = function coinConvert(usDollars) {
  
  var arr = [];
  var peruvianSoles = usDollars * arr[0];
  var mexicanPesos =  usDollars * arr [1];
  var chileanPesos =  usDollars * arr[2];
  console.log = (peruvianSoles, mexicanPesos, chileanPesos);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en soles
  arr.push(3.25);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos mexicanos
  arr.push(18);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos chilenos
  arr.push(660);

  return arr;
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quiza te falta el `;` al finalizar el console.log y la funcion export no termina con `};` solo dejalo `}`

Comment: el código se detiene en la linea de `module.exports = function coinConvert(usDollars)`

Comment: para mi esta respuesta requieres que hagas un poco mas de analisis, para mi deberia ser cerrada; de igual forma te recomiendo ver cuando hacer el push y cual es el factor de cambio para las monedas, una vez solucionado esto creo que debes agregar tu pregunta

Comment: ReferenceError: module is not defined :'v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo estas usando Javascript debería ser así, aunque no entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer, ya que haces `usDollars * arr[0]` cuando ese arr esta vació.

Entonces bastara cambiar la posición en que haces la operación. Es decir primero agregamos elementos al array y luego hacemos la multiplicación.

otro error es:   `console.log = (peruvianSoles, mexicanPesos, chileanPesos);`
 Cuando debería ser   `console.log(peruvianSoles, mexicanPesos, chileanPesos);`

```js
exports = function coinConvert(usDollars) {
  var arr = [];
  // Añade el monto equivalente en soles
  arr.push(3.25);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos mexicanos
  arr.push(18);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos chilenos
  arr.push(660);
  
  //Operamos
  var peruvianSoles = usDollars * arr[0];
  var mexicanPesos =  usDollars * arr [1];
  var chileanPesos =  usDollars * arr[2];
  
  //Mostramos en consola
    console.log("Dentro de la funcion:--> " + peruvianSoles + " , " + mexicanPesos  + " , " + chileanPesos);

//retornamos el array
  return arr;
};



//Aquí puedes cambiar el parametro que recibe Ej: exports(50) , exports(1000), etc. 
console.log("El retorno de la funcion coinConvert: --> " + exports(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar solo `exports`

```
exports = function coinConvert(usDollars) {

  var arr = [];
    // Añade el monto equivalente en soles
  arr.push(3.25);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos mexicanos
  arr.push(18);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos chilenos
  arr.push(660);
  var peruvianSoles = usDollars * arr[0];
  var mexicanPesos =  usDollars * arr [1];
  var chileanPesos =  usDollars * arr[2];
  console.log = (peruvianSoles, mexicanPesos, chileanPesos);      
  return arr;
};
```

¿Te funciono?

Comment: en realidad la funcion le sirve

Comment: Si vas a usar Stack Snippet deberías incluir algo para mostrar el resultado ya sea en el HTML o en la consola de otra forma no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 0):

El error que te marca es con respecto a `console.log` que es una función sin embargo la estas igualando a algo:

```
console.log = (peruvianSoles, mexicanPesos, chileanPesos);
```

y por otro lado tienes un error lógico el cual estas multiplicando usDollars con variables del arreglo siendo que el arreglo esta vacio

```
var arr = []; // Arreglo vacio
var peruvianSoles = usDollars * arr[0];
var mexicanPesos =  usDollars * arr [1];
var chileanPesos =  usDollars * arr[2];
```

aquí esta tu código corregido

```js
var module = {};    
module.exports = function coinConvert(usDollars) {
  
  var arr = [];
  var peruvianSoles = usDollars * arr[0];
  var mexicanPesos =  usDollars * arr [1];
  var chileanPesos =  usDollars * arr[2];
  console.log(peruvianSoles, mexicanPesos, chileanPesos);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en soles
  arr.push(3.25);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos mexicanos
  arr.push(18);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos chilenos
  arr.push(660);

  return arr;
};
```

PD: en javascript no es necesario terminar una línea de código con `;`, puedes simplemente hacerlo con salto de línea (enter)

PD2: agregue `var module = {};` solo para que funcione el code snippet, tu probablemente ya tengas esto en otra parte del código, no lo agregues.

Espero te sirva